# Receive email in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email

Is there anyway to receive email in mvc, I'm imagining it probably involves setting up a smtp server and having the app poll every so often.

The scenario I am thinking of is tracking emails that are not being able to be sent for various reasons like invalid email address, receipient server down etc and we'd like to track those so we know whats going on and read the error response we are sent.

The other thing I'm not 100% sure of its how you would tie the messages together, I'm guessing you could do a reasonable job with checking the message title and recipients but a better way might be to specify a custom header however I'm not sure if these would still get sent by the mailer when they are replying back to us with the error, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've done this before but I use the third-party commercial component for ASP so I'm not sure that what is your main operating system server or whatsoever.

But you might check the source code and the component as well to help you through and build this application.

The source code is dope and wide, you might download, check and learn from that.

[Link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/webmail/)

Hope this helps and GBU

Comment: this seems to be a UI component for displaying email, doenst have anything to do with receiving mail, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Have you tried to open and test it? I've done integrating the email but I haven't tried to send the email.